# Coinbase and Kraken Transfer Costs

Tags: exchanges, fees, wallet-transfer

I just did my first transfer of ETH from Coinbase to Kraken, to see how it would work.

I transferred 1 ETH, and Coinbase indicated that the transfer charge (the gas) would be .00042 ETH (as I would have expected).  The total transfer out of Coinbase was 1.00042.

I expected 1 ETH to arrive in my Kraken account.  But, only .99938 ETH arrived.  At some point, .00062 ETH was "lost."

Since the gas was already covered, Coinbase indicated that there was no additional fee on their end, and Kraken indicated there was no additional fee on their end, I can't figure out where the .00062 ETH went.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you can provide the transaction ids for the above, you should be able to trace it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Here is the Tx hash for the transaction...but, I can't interpret the information well enough to determine where the fees went...

 0x3d2218451e3b77218d1be91589b8be6832faa0a53d55f40ebd6f58d72e63d26c

Comment: That transaction doesn't show up in etherscan.io - is there a typo perhaps? Maybe post a link to the transaction on etherscan.io.

Comment: Appreciate your help!  Here you go:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3d2218451e3b77218d1be91589b8be6832faa0a53d55f40ebd6f58d72e63d26c

Comment: How did you go about transferring form coinbase to kraken? I am new to this coin business and coinbase closed my account for NO reason. I want to transfer to KRaken but don't know how.

Comment: Can you transfer less than 1ETH ?

Answer (score 8):

I see what happened.

1ETH was transferred:
from 0x2bF0011e4da5a841CE9459c0995Bb2646c4f1D21 (coinbase)
to 0xd08436533f63b1342fB89198F963acD8589657AE (intermediary address)
with a gas cost of (21000 * 0.00000002)ETH
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3d2218451e3b77218d1be91589b8be6832faa0a53d55f40ebd6f58d72e63d26c

then, from this intermediary address, there was a transfer of 0.99938038ETH:
from 0xd08436533f63b1342fB89198F963acD8589657AE (intermediary address)
to 0xFa52274DD61E1643d2205169732f29114BC240b3 (kraken smart contract address?)
with a gas cost of (30981 * 0.00000002) = 0.00061962ETH
and 0.99938038 + 0.00061962 = 1ETH
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xef5b7451006a6315604c82e4088e298a57105b7d6f1b728f74387efea55eaac0

So in other words, your transaction from coinbase to kraken hopped through an intermediary address. This hop had a gas cost equal to the amount you're missing from your original 1ETH.

As to what the intermediary contract is - I'm not sure...